# Is there any way to force Internet Explorer to break on alert()?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to debug an error message in a large and complicated frames based web/ASP.Net app using IE8 and Visual Studio 2010. Specifically, I am getting a "Member not found" message box which appears to be a straightforward JavaScript `alert()`. Unfortunately I don't know where in the code the problem is happening, and fiddler2 wasn't much help in this case.

My question is, can I get IE to break at the `alert()` call so that I can debug it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String search for "Member not found"

Add `1 / 0;` before the line.

Turn on break on all errors.

(I assumed you knew the developer tool existed. Hit F12 and navigate to the script tab)

**Edit:**

Thanks to @DmitriyNaumov

```
var aalert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() {
  aalert.apply(this, arguments);
  1 / 0;
}
```

Comment: or rewrite alert with custom function that does 1 / 0;

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18359) from Microsoft. I don't know if it allows you to Set JS breakpoints, but it is a great tool to have on hand anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You  can use the IE debugger , press <kbd>F12</kbd> and then under the script tab you can add breakpoints

Comment: I've done this in IE 8; just switch to the 'Script' tab and click the 'Break All'/pause (Ctrl + Shift + B) button when the alert is displayed. It will break in the JavaScript once you close the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Using IE 8 you can use Developer Tools which is a little like Firebug for Mozilla Firefox.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359

(for more information)

this way you can create breakpoints and debug the script execution on the page step by step

Just press F12

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this doesn't help because if I knew where to set the breakpoint I wouldn't be asking the question :) To put it another way, I need to find *where* the error is happening, preferably without setting a ton of breakpoints.

Comment: sorry... but then again... use the debug! it's pretty straightforward... go step by step... you don't actually need the breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Change `alert` into a new function that throws a proper error.

```
window.alert = function(msg) {
  throw "Alert: " + msg;
};
```

Older versions of IE don't allow overwriting window properties like alert in this way in JavaScript ... but you can still do it with VBScript.

```
Sub alert(msg)
  Err.Raise 8, "Alert", msg
End Sub
```

If you go the VBScript route, make sure it precedes any JavaScript that references the `alert` function, or you'll have missed your opportunity.

Comment: Define "Older versions of IE" I'm sure IE6+ let's you do this.

Comment: When I tried IE 6 in the past (circa 2008), it would not let me override default window functions like alert() and prompt().  It's possible that patches issued since this time have made it possible.  At the time, on a whim, I chose to explore the vbscript option, and that allowed be to overwrite window functions.

Comment: I just fired up an XP VM with vanilla IE 6 and tried both approaches.  In JS, setting "alert = ..." throws "Error: Object doesn't support this action".  Setting "window.alert = " merely fails silently.  Using the VBScript code I listed above works as described.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a window.alert, you can do this:

1. Enable external debuggers in IE.
2. Attach visual studio as a script debugger.
3. Reproduce the problem.
4. While the alert box is shown, break in the debugger.
5. When you dismiss the alert, the debugger will be paused on the next line of code.
6. Use the current call stack to set a breakpoint where ever before the call will be most useful for the next time.

Unfortunately this trick only applies to alert and confirm, since they are modal dialogs.